# How to access a dynamically generated id of a submit button?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a submit button that has got a dynamically generated id. I want to make this button invisible once it was clicked once. At the same time another button which is invisible when the page loads will become visible instead.

But how can I reference the button I want to make invisible if the id is generated dynamically. I know the id always starts with the string 'product_'. Can I use left/substring somehow to get control of this button? And how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery. You need to use [live](http://jqapi.com/#p=live) or [delegate](http://jqapi.com/#p=delegate) methods to access a dynamically generated ids

```
$('button[id^="product_"]').live('click', function(){alert("Hi");})
```

Comment: Thank you Londeren, this is exactly what I wanted, tried it and it works!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$("button[id^='product_']")
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you could give your two buttons unique css class names then you do not need to worry about the id's?